# Reference python object in an imported function

Tags: python, object, import

I have two .py script files. The "main" script will import the second script containing misc "helper" functions.

In the main script, I have set up an object for a SPI interface. I would like to write functions in the imported file that use the SPI interface directly. I'm a noob at this and tried writing and passing in various ways but always get errors.

**mainscript.py**

```
import helperfunctions.py as helper

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)

response = spi.xfer([ ... some data ...])  #this works when
                                           #called from mainscript.py

helper.sendOtherStuff()  #this doesn't work (see helper script below)
```

**helperfunctions.py**

```
def sendOtherStuff():
   #need to somehow reference 'spi.' object from mainscript.py file 
   otherData = ([... some different data ...])
   resp = spi.xfer([otherData])  #this fails because helperfunctions
                                 #apparently doesn't know spi. object
   return resp
```

I have the same general question often regarding global variable values as well. I'm sure there is a "better" way to do it, but out of convenience for now, I often wish to define some global variables in mainscript.py then reference those globals inside functions of helperfunctions.py. I can't figure a way to do this. Going the other way is easy - declare the globals inside helperfunctions.py then reference them from mainscript.py as helper.variableName, but I don't know how to go the other direction.

Any direction is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have a circular import issue. Btw, you don't need `.py` suffix when importing a file or a module. Just do `import helperfunctions as helper`. Helper functions inherently don't need any external object or module to work. Because they are just helpers. I think you should revise your code architecture. *(For instance, you can define your helper function in a way that they take `spi` as a parameter.)*

Comment: Thank you ozgur. I had tried passing as a parameter but wasn't sure how to actually execute the object once inside the function. The example from Robert below looks to have solved this. Make sense. I'll look forward to trying in the morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By my lights the easiest thing to do would be to pass the spi object to the helper function as a parameter:

```
def sendOtherStuff(spi):
    otherData = ([... some different data ...])  
    return spi.xfer([otherData])
```

Once it's passed in, you can call methods on it in the body of the function. I removed your variable assignment because it seemed redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the code example. That makes sense. To clarify so I understand... when passing the object into the function, by simply calling it in the return, this causes it to be run? It looks that way from your example. I wasn't aware of this - looks like exactly what I have been missing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again guys. This was it. Works as expected.